# What is causing my Screen to turn right back on after it's turned off (by power settings) in lubuntu?

Tags: lubuntu

I've tried to look this up on Google with no helpful results on resolving this power management issue. I have also tried to turn off the screen manually by doing this command:

> xset dpms force off

But that didn't work either, the screen just turns back on. I have even tried to change different settings in xfce4 power manager with no success in removing this issue.

What is causing this issue? I feel like I've tried everything I could, and still nothing. Thanks for any answers.

Comment: Any mouse or keyboard event? Read `man xev`.

Comment: Hm. Doesn't appear to say anything when the screen turns off and back on, except when the xfce4 notification comes up.